# OpenVPN with node, How it works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vpn

I am able to connect to a VPN from terminal easily with the following openVPN command:

```
openvpn --config conf.ovpn
```

I need connect to the same VPN with Javascript (for selenium test), I already have installed **openvpn.client** with NPM:

```
npm install openvpn-client
```

However, I don't know how it works. I would like how to achieve a terminal application with similar functionalities of openvpn.

Documentation and source code

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/openvpn-client
- https://github.com/resin-io/openvpn-client

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you've answered your own question you can post the answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Good to Know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, more or less...

After install openvpn in the system just add bit s to the openvpn bin (sudo chmod +s /usr/sbin/openvpn), then you can connect openvpn with this:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

cmd = `openvpn --config ${conf.ovpn}&`;
exec(cmd);
```

Just that. Maybe isn't the most secure solution, but it works for my purpose.

Thanks.